# How to change the sequence order without dropping the sequence in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sequence

my current sequence no is 203 i need to jump to 1203 without dropping the sequence.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

First alter the sequence increment, given you stated 203 to 1203, I'm adding 1000, adjust as appropriate.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE yourSequence INCREMENT BY 1000;
```

Then request a value

```
SELECT yourSequence.NextVal FROM dual;
```

Then alter it back to incrementing by 1 (assuming it was 1 in the first place)

```
ALTER SEQUENCE yourSequence INCREMENT BY 1;
```

You really don't want to do this if the sequence is in active use - since it could jump up multiple thousands.

Answer (score 3):

You may create such a procedure on your desired schema of DB as follows :

```
SQL>Create or Replace Procedure Pr_Set_Sequence( i_seq_name varchar2, i_val pls_integer ) is
   v_val     pls_integer;
begin
  for c in (
            Select u.sequence_name seq
              From User_Sequences u
             Where u.sequence_name = upper(i_seq_name)
           ) 
  loop  
    execute immediate 'select '||i_seq_name||'.nextval from dual' INTO v_val;
    execute immediate 'alter sequence '||i_seq_name||' increment by ' ||
                                               to_char(-v_val+i_val) || ' minvalue 0';
    execute immediate 'select '||i_seq_name||'.nextval from dual' INTO v_val;
    execute immediate 'alter sequence '||i_seq_name||' increment by 1 minvalue 0';
  end loop;  
end;
```

and call with the desired value ( in my case a create a new one called `my_seq` ) :

```
SQL> create sequence my_seq;

Sequence created

SQL> select my_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1

SQL> begin
  2     pr_set_sequence('my_seq',1203);
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> select my_seq.currval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
      1203
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a WHILE loop, selecting from the sequence until it's up to the value you need.  It's quite fast.

```
declare
  v_sequence_value       number;
begin
  while v_sequence_value <= 1203 loop
    select my_sequence.nextval into v_sequence_value from dual;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Just need to add before the while 
select ietp_email.dmeid.nextval into v_sequence_value from dual; 
so v_sequence_value has a value.