# how to reset id start from 1 in apex after deleting multiple rows in a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I delete 10 rows in a table and after inserting row data it should start from 1 
  but it start from 11
how i can fix it in apex

[image]

Comment: you may refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51443457/how-to-change-the-sequence-order-without-dropping-the-sequence-in-oracle/51444442#51444442 ( by this way you may reset your sequence to any integer you want )

Comment: It is the PT_ID column, right? Sounds like a candidate for a primary/unique key. If that's so, what you want would work only if you delete all rows from the table. Otherwise, sooner or later you'll violate uniqueness. What business problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Why do you need to reset this sequence? There's nothing wrong with a primary key id to not start at 1. Sequences are NOT guaranteed to give you a gap-free series of numbers.